# RSH & REXEC from Windows 2008 Server to AIX Unix Box

Tags: unix, windows-server-2008, rsh, rexec

Is anyone aware of how to call a RSH and REXEC command from a script on a windows 2008R2 server to a AIX Unix box - The commands worked under 2003 Server with the unix addons installed but not 2008